# Symmetry for a Lagrangian system

Tags: classical-mechanics

Given the Lagrangian
$$L(x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y},t)=y^2\dot{x}^2+x^2\dot{y}^2+x+y+\dot{x}t+\dot{y}t
$$
in the $x,y$ coordinates, I want to find some conserved quantities. Since there are no cyclic coordinates, I am searching for a symmetry for the system but I'm not sure how to do that. Is there any method I could use?

Comment: Just saying that this is a very very very big Lagrangian.

Comment: I am curious about this Lagrangian. May you tell if it's homework or whatever? And if homework, what's the solution provided. I know what's the coordinate change leading to that Lagrangian and I'd like to know if at least you got it and what you were said.

Comment: Yes, It's homework. I just had to say which of three given quantities was a constant of motion for the Lagrangian, but I was curious to find a symmetry. The solution provided is exactly the one I accepted.

Comment: @Rafael Wagner and magnetissimo, thanks! I am sure now what's the coordinate transformation leading from that lagrangian to the one for a free particle. I asked for someting very related and I got a nice complete answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129155/curvature-of-the-metric-ds2-y2dx2x2dy2) Somebody put the "Homework" tag, but it isn't :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we can write the lagrangian in this form:

$$L(x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y},t)=y^2\dot{x}^2+x^2\dot{y}^2+x+y+\dot{x}t+\dot{y}t=$$

$$=y^2\dot{x}^2+x^2\dot{y}^2+\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(xt+yt)$$

We can drop the total derivative with respect to time because it doesn't affect the equations of motion:

$$\tilde L(x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y},t)=y^2\dot{x}^2+x^2\dot{y}^2$$

Now, as the lagrangian doesn't depend explicitly of time, [the energy is conserved](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158401/conservation-of-energy-when-the-lagrangian-includes-a-potential-function). So is,

$\dot x\dfrac{\partial\tilde L}{\partial\dot x}+\dot y\dfrac{\partial\tilde L}{\partial\dot y}-\tilde L=K$

$\dot x\dfrac{\partial\tilde L}{\partial\dot x}+\dot y\dfrac{\partial\tilde L}{\partial\dot y}-\tilde L=\dot xy^22\dot x+\dot yx^22\dot y-y^2\dot x^2-x^2\dot y^2=y^2\dot x^2+x^2\dot y^2$

$y^2\dot x^2+x^2\dot y^2=K$

I tink this lagrangian is simply the one for the free particle in dimension two, but in a weird coordinate system.

Comment: Great answer! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

To find conserved quantities there is nothing better then derive the canonical equations of Hamilton. So I have the hint

**Hint:** Find the Hamiltonian and the [canonical equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonsEquations.html) of motion for the hamiltonian system

> $$\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial q} = -\dot{p} \hspace{2cm} \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial p} =  \dot{q}$$

You should of course find the equations of motion for the Lagrangian, i.e., the Euler-Lagrange equations.

If you are searching specifically for a symmetry there is the most beatifull theorem of physics (my personal opinion), so the other hint should be

**Hint:** Use [Noether's Theorem](http://phys.columbia.edu/~nicolis/NewFiles/Noether_theorem.pdf) to find a symmetry. If you read the link you should see that, in the notation used,

> $$\sum_\alpha \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q_\alpha}}\gamma_\alpha = \text{constant}$$

The theorem says that for a specific symmetry you always can find  conserved quantities. *See that if you change $x \rightarrow y$ you get the same Lagrangian*.

---